# FileHandle don't free memory in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I'll send large file to server. The file will be separated to chunks. I receive high memory consumption when I call FileHandle.readData(ofLength:). Memory for chunk don't deallocate, and after some time I receive EOM exception and crash.
Profiler show problem in FileHandle.readData(ofLength:) (see screenshots)

```
func nextChunk(then: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        self.previousOffset = self.fileHandle.offsetInFile
        autoreleasepool {
            let data = self.fileHandle.readData(ofLength: Constants.chunkLength)
            if data == Constants.endOfFile {
                then(nil)
            } else {
                then(data)
                self.currentChunk += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you calling this method? Every chunk of data you pass off to somewhere else via `then(data)`, so it depends on how long the _recipient_ of the data holds on to it that will determine when the memory is freed. Also, how big are the files you're reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocations tool is simply showing you where the unreleased memory was initially allocated. It is up to you to figure out what you subsequently did with that object and why it was not released in a timely manner. None of the profiling tools can help you with that. They can only point to where the object was originally allocated, which is only the starting point for your research.

One possible problem might be if you are creating `Data`-based `URLRequest` objects. That means that while the associated `URLSessionTask` requests are in progress, the `Data` is held in memory. If so, you might consider using a file-based `uploadTask` instead. That prevents the holding the `Data` associated with the body of the request in memory.

Once your start using file-based `uploadTask`, that begs the question as to whether you need/want to break it up into chunks at all. A file-based `uploadTask`, even when sending very large assets, requires very little RAM at runtime. And, at some future point in time, you may even consider using a background session, so the uploads will continue even if the user leaves the app. The combination of these features may obviate the chunking altogether.

As you may have surmised, the `autoreleasepool` may be unnecessary. That is intended to solve a very specific problem (where one create and release autorelease objects in a tight loop). I suspect your problem rests elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's true! Changing data to file in uploadTask code resolved memory issue!